# Svelte with rxjs Observable in object property

Tags: rxjs, svelte, rxjs-observables, svelte-component

I'm trying to use an rxjs Observable in Svelte rendering.  I understand I can do that :

```
<span>{$myObservable}</span>
```

but what if myObservable is inside an object:

```
<span>{$myObject.myObservable}</span>
```

the "$" now gives me the error :

> (Stores must be declared at the top level of the component (this may
> change in a future version of Svelte)

Anyone has a workaround for that?

Example here :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/testsveltebindrxjs?file=src%2FApp.svelte&terminal=dev

Comment: Well I'm using rxjs at some places because it's much more powerful than svelte stores for some operations.  And rxjs is actually working fine with Svelte auto subscription. But the issue here is not really about stores or rxjs, its about using the "$" when the Observable (or Store) is in a class property.

Comment: @Corrl Actually, Svelte was designed to support using any other Observable implementation(such as rxjs Observable) instead of svelte store (svelte store is an observable implementation itself). Just look at this pull request:

https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/2556

Answer (score 1):

If you do the exact same thing as you did, but with stores as you can see in this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/testsveltebindrxjs-rzypbp?file=src%2FApp.svelte&terminal=dev).

If you access the property this way: `$counter.counterStore`, you get this error message:

```
Stores must be declared at the top level of the component (this may change in a future version of Svelte)
```

So this means that svelte stores were not designed to be inside an object, but declared at the top level of a file.

rxjs support in svelte comes from the fact that svelte store were design to have a compatible interface with other Observable implementations, so this same rule will apply to rxjs observables.

So I suppose it is not possible in svelte.